Flux Deployment To EKS Issue
I am trying to deploy my app to AWS EKS every time a new image is pushed into ECR automatically using Flux. Basically deploy the image to EKS. I think I have everything configured but it doesn't do it automatically. It deploys when I try to run the command - 'kubectl rollout restart deployment "app-name" -n flux-system'.
I am attaching the link to my github repo - https://github.com/Infotrend-Inc/COMET-FLUX/tree/main/clusters/eks
Any help would be appreciated.

Do you have think to create trigger on AWS ?
